# Retrieving available sharing options on device and share over it using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

By using simple sharing intent it displays sharing options like below

[image: Share options using simple sharing intent]

**Now** , how about do something like this below SS ??

[image]

I searched about it , But without having any result  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by creating this plugin by myself

https://pub.dev/packages/share_options

thanks <3